# Delphi equivalent - C# Expression<Func<T, object>>

Tags: c#, delphi, expression

Does Delphi Berlin supports Expression trees like C#?

```
Expression<Func<T, object>>
```

I have been searching this, but found nothing. I only found about anonymous functions but not expression trees.

How can I achieve something like this in Delphi?

```
    private string Select<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] expression)
    {
        return ...
    }
```

Example:

```
Select<Customer>(x=> x.Name, x=> x.Id, x=> x.Address)
```

The main objective is to execute the function passing a class properties to create a string using those property´s names.

Comment: No, not directly. I guess that it is possible and probably someone already implemented it one way or the other. But then you get into the realm of recommendations, which are off-topic questions. There is no lambda or lambda-like syntax in Delphi (yet), that is certain.

Comment: FWIW, params is the equivalent of Delphi's [open array parameters (link to my article)](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html).

Comment: No there is not. The C# compiler has knowledge about `Expression<T>` and turns it into an expression tree. No way to do that in Delphi. There are other approaches to get as close as possible to LINQ but none of them really matches what `Expression<T>` can do

Comment: You probably wanted sometthing like this https://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2011/05/lambdas-and-expression-trees-in-delphi.html